# @font-face only works on local server (XAMPP)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

For some strange reason, when I try to upload the font to my web server. It doesn't work. The @font-face works on my local server.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Mustang;
    src: url("../fonts/mustang.otf");
}



h1.header {
    font-family: Mustang;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access the direct link to the font file?

Comment: @Ibrahim Forbidden. Apparently I don't have permission.

Comment: Try to set the mime type for otf files in your .htaccess file:
AddType font/opentype .otf

Comment: @Ibrahim Do I need to replace 'opentype.otf' with 'mustan.otf'?

Comment: No, just keep it as it is font/opentype (also note the space between opentype and .otf)

Comment: @Ibrahim  So the .HTACCESS file should just include: `AddType font/opentype .otf`?

Comment: Yes, just append that line to the end of the .htaccess file. If you don't have any .htaccess file create one.

Comment: @Ibrahim Sadly that didn't work.

Comment: Try to set the permissions to the font file to 666 and if that does not work, try adding this in the .htaccess file:
`<FilesMatch "\.(otf|woff)$">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: @Ibrahim Again, still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the mime type that your web server delivers the fonts with and post it here. Is it `application/octet-stream` (which I am assuming)? Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Post the link to your webserver.

Comment: Have you checked the browsers console for errors?